# How to change button color in flutter?

Tags: flutter

''' builder: (_) => NetworkGiffyDialog(
title: Text('لايوجد اتصال',

```
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
            description: Text(
              'يبدو أنك غير متصل بالانترنت.يرجى التحقق من اعدادات الشبكة الخاصة بك مرة أخرى',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            entryAnimation: EntryAnimation.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
            onOkButtonPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            key: key,
            image: Image.asset("assets/no-internet.jpeg"),
            onCancelButtonPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
        buttonOkColor:Colors.black,//Color(0xff8e1538),
        buttonCancelColor: Color(0xff8e1538),
            buttonOkText: Text('تاكد'),
            buttonCancelText: Text("الغاء"),
          ));
});
```

} '''
I want to change the button color to the one i specified in the code(0xff8e1538).

Comment: buttonOkColor:Color(0xff8e1538)

Comment: what type of button are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which type of button you are using, but for most of the buttons in Flutter, you can use the **style** property, with the ***name_of_the_button_you_use.styleFrom***. Here is an example for the OutlinedButton:

```
OutlinedButton(
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff8e1538), //this is the background color
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 3), //you can also change the border color with this line
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(),
)
```